# bitbake: cannot link against usbserial for module cp210x

Tags: embedded-linux, kernel-module, beagleboneblack, bitbake, usbserial

I worked through following tutorial http://www.jumpnowtek.com/beaglebone/BeagleBone-Systems-with-Yocto.html
with my BBB (rev c) and everything worked fine. My next step was migrate a usb kernel module from my host (ubuntu 16.04.3) where the usb driver was working as expected.

The recipe to create the module also works but here is the problem:
When I `insmod` my module I receive:

```
insmod /lib/modules/4.8.12-yocto-standard/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/cp210x.ko
cp210x: Unknown symbol usb_serial_generic_open (err 0)
cp210x: Unknown symbol usb_serial_generic_close (err 0)
cp210x: Unknown symbol usb_serial_deregister_drivers (err 0)
cp210x: Unknown symbol usb_serial_register_drivers (err 0)
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/4.8.12-yocto-standard/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/cp210x.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

Now looking into the module symbol table shows:

```
nm -u /lib/modules/4.8.12-yocto-standard/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/cp210x.ko
         U __aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1
         U __gnu_mcount_nc
         U __kmalloc
         U __memzero
         U arm_copy_from_user
         U arm_copy_to_user
         U dev_err
         U dev_warn
         U kfree
         U kmalloc_caches
         U kmem_cache_alloc_trace
         U tty_encode_baud_rate
         U usb_control_msg
         U usb_serial_deregister_drivers
         U usb_serial_generic_close
         U usb_serial_generic_open
         U usb_serial_register_drivers
```

However on my host system those symbols are linked into `usbserial.ko`.
Yet I did not find any recipe that provides the missing symbols. Is a usbserial library or package or recipe available to satisfy the dependency?

Comment: Thanky you for that suggestition, but usbserial is not yet part of my rootfs archive. I need to know how I can enable usbserial to be created in my bitbake (yocto) build.

Comment: I've no experience with working on menuconfig with yocto and just a little in general. Stupid question, I ran the menuconfig but what name shall I save it to? I am searching for a solution regarding the config files (e.g. .bb, .bbappend or .conf) in the first place. But solving the issue is first prio...

Comment: I tried that several times, it turned out I was on kind of the right way, just in the wrong or incomplete order. More details in the answer later. Thanks again!!